# Create dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need some enlightenment to create dictionary from the value returned. i only can see the last value in the dictionary.

The value of bgp_net

```
 network 10.29.92.76 mask 255.255.255.255
 network 10.29.92.77 mask 255.255.255.255
 network 10.29.92.83 mask 255.255.255.255
 network 10.237.32.0 mask 255.255.255.224
 network 10.239.1.101 mask 255.255.255.255
```

> 

```
bgp_network_adv = {}
bgp_network = confparse.find_all_children(r"^router bgp")
for network in bgp_network:
    if 'network' in network:
        bgp_net= network.strip().split(' ')[1:4:2]
        bgp_network_adv = {'network':([a for a in bgp_net])}
        print (bgp_network_adv)
```

Ouput

```
   {'network': ['10.239.1.101', '255.255.255.255']}
```

i am expecting to get the rest of the value stored in the dictionary.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict.setdefault` with `list.extend`

**Ex:**

```
for network in bgp_network:
    if 'network' in network:
        bgp_net= network.strip().split()[1:4:2]
        bgp_network_adv.setdefault('network',[]).extend(bgp_net)
        print (bgp_network_adv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have unique `key` for each `key/value` pair. In your code, you are setting key to `network` for all pairs. So, it is getting overwritten. You should look for another model to store data. One way can be to append a counter to your key. For example:

```
network0
network1
network2
...
```